# SwiftUI Link to open Bundle files in browser

Tags: url, swiftui, bundle

You can get the browser to open a URL with one line of code...

```
Link("Info", destination: URL(string: "https://my.web.address/info.pdf")!)
```

You can compile and build this....

```
Link("Info", destination: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "info", withExtension: "pdf")!)
```

No errors or crashes, but it does nothing. The Bundle.main.url() reply makes sense within the application, but does not work in the browser, which is not in the application. This was a security feature to stop people pulling data from your application, according to an answer from about 10 years back.

I have written a WKWebView page within my application to display the file. This works, but it took a lot more than one line. I would have actually preferred my original solution, if there had been some way for me to mark certain files as suitable for public release. As well as the manual, I have a PDF test chart image, and a table of CSV data that I would like to make public like this. I could use a button in the app to open them in the browser, and the user could then save a copy when and where they wanted. The user gets to re-use their browser skills, and I write one line of code per file. Win-win, right?

Can we open a Bundled file in the browser using a Link using some trick I haven't found yet? Is there a good reason why we must not do this?

Apologies if you have read (and possibly deleted) a question like this earlier today. I wrote this question, and I thought I had submitted it, but I can't find it now. So here it is again.

FWIW, here's my WKWebView page code...

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit


struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = WKWebView
    
    var webView: WKWebView
    
    init() {
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ByEye", withExtension: "pdf")!))
    }
    
    // Needed to make view UIViewRepresentable
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView { webView }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) { }
}

struct ManualView: View {
    
    var webView = WebView()
    
    var body: some View {
        webView
    }
}


struct ManualView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ManualView()
    }
}
```

I found a partial solution. You can add text or images to the pasteboard, and then paste the data into an e-mail or other message. This does not work for a general file type, but it was enough to get me where I wanted.

See [questions/74784691/swiftui-sharing-application-data-using-pasteboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74784691/swiftui-sharing-application-data-using-pasteboard)

Comment: What if you make an HTML page with the PDF (using the `embed` tag) and load the HTML file in the in-app browser? Also, did you already look into the PDFKit framework?

Comment: I have added my WebKit code. A quick look tells me PDFKit code would be about the same. WebKit let try PDF, EPUB, HTML, DOC, and Rich Text. The OfficeLibre PDF file was much smaller than the others and looked better first go.

The Link solution was neater IMHO. I could have a list of Links in the body, and the browser could downloads, several links being open at once, and other stuff. But it only works if I can turn Bundle.main.url into a proper url with a path.

I am investigating the embed tag. Thanks for that.